# Why am I not able to match multiple lines with this regex on rubular?

Tags: ruby, regex, devise, rubular

I'm working with the following regex (taken from the `devise.rb` file that [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) generates):

```
\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z
```

Usually, when I'm learning about a regex I use [rubular](http://rubular.com/). For example, if I wanted to learn about the regex `/.a./`, I would set up my workspace as shown [here](http://rubular.com/r/Hss60Tj0VJ):

[image]

Notice how I'm using multiple examples:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

And rubular is giving me feedback that both `bar` and `baz` match.

Now I'd like to learn about the regex that devise generates: `/\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/`. So I set up my rubular workspace as shown here [here](http://rubular.com/r/1YAEL1nLka):

[image]

There isn't a match. It's because I have two examples:

```
foo@foo.com
cats@cat.com
```

But I was expecting them both to match. Why aren't both test strings matching?

Comment: Rubular tests on a string. The words "Your test string:" above the appropriate box is the clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the regex `/\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/` is matching the start of the string with `\A` and end of the string with `\z`.

If you remove both `\A` and `\z` and instead try to match `/[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+/` then it will match both email addresses as shown [here](http://rubular.com/r/SnCrmjvtI6):

[image]

Also, it's worth mentioning that the start and end of a **string** is different from the start and end of a **line**. Each are represented by four different patterns shown below and also on rubular in the [Regex quick reference](http://rubular.com/):

```
^   - Start of line
$   - End of line
\A  - Start of string
\z  - End of string
```

There can be multiple *lines* in a *string*; however, a single string goes from `\A` to `\z`. So to continue with this multiple email example. Replacing the start and end of a string patterns with the start and end of a line patterns to get: `/^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+$/` will also match, shown below and on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/nZ5W3VUrsc):

[image]